# Extract additional Java attributes from a passed object in html

Tags: java, html, jsp, security

Suppose I have a table of users that have the attributes "login" and "password". I select them from my DB:

`Query query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT u FROM User u");`

`List<User> resultList = query.getResultList();`

Then I pass the list into a jsp view and iterate over it, printing user logins:

`<s:property value=user.login/>`

Is it possible on the client's side to also view the users' passwords, considering they do (I assume) exist in the page's source code? If it is, how is it done?

Or are unused object attributes inaccessble in interpreted HTML?

Answer (score 0):

Yes that's possible , you already have a class `User` which has the attributes `login` and `password` , so you can extract the login and password and inject them into objects

```
Query query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT login,passowrd FROM User");
...
// for each line on table
User u = new User(login,password); // extracted from the query
user_list.add(u); // add it to the list you'll send to jsp
```

Then when you pass the list into JSP , you can extract them with getters :

```
<s:property value=user.login/>
<s:property value=user.password/>
```

Comment: But I meant, can it be done if I ONLY display logins in JSP? Can someone browsing the page access the User object and get its other property, without me choosing to render it?

Comment: No he cant , because this code running is a server side and not a client side